# Downvoting after I downvoted someone for giving a wrong answer

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, serial-voting

So, I downvoted someone on SO and commented WHY I did it. His answer was not what the question asked. In my opinion this is how the system works, right? So, directly after that I got 3 downvotes on other answers I posted in other questions. I thought, ok what a stupid.. But, now, the day after, I again got 6-8 downvotes..

What to do about this? It's not that I care loosing rep, it's more like it shouldn't be right to downvote good answers. Here's some examples:

[how to join two multidimensional arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109815/how-to-join-two-multidimensional-arrays-in-php/19109864#19109864) (+9 | -1)

[What is the meaning of form action="/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022150/what-is-the-meaning-of-form-action/19022170#19022170) (+9 | -1)

[Getting a record from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999609/getting-a-record-from-another-table/20999764#20999764) (+7 | -1)

[image]

This won't be turned around by the system as it's not seen as serial downvoting.. So my question is: What can you actually do to prevent people like this from downvoting others they don't like? Do you need to flag it for a moderator?

Comment: You cannot prevent people from doing this. The linked question gives you the other options; you can flag a post and explain what you think is happening, but moderators cannot do much but collect info about someone possibly evading the serial voting script deliberately.

Comment: Ick, that was meant to be closed as a dupe of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829).

Comment: Don't worry, the system should pick up the events in the screenshot. I would be surprised if it doesn't. As it will pick up the upvotes you have received just now. Someone doesn't seem to know whether to love or hate you. ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hard players don't need to do that, they simply do "independant" downvote. On wikipedia this type of behavior is named as "flesh-puppet". This was probably a light-weight amateur try, which will be fixed next midnight automatically.

Comment: Related: [What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212332), linked from the FAQ I tried to dupe you to.

Comment: Thanks all, got my answer!